# No viable overloaded '=' when using std::remove_if()

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a sliding-window that slides with time and removes oldest data as a template class. I am using std::map as container and std::chrono to manipulate time.
I have a compile time error in the method responsible for deleting data older than X milliseconds :

```
include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_pair.h:170:8: error: no viable overloaded '='
    first = std::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
```

I don't understand why `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` has no viable "operator =".
I use clang++ compiler.

Here is the template code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <class Data, class Clock, class Time = typename Clock::time_point>

class TimeSlideWindow {
private:
    std::map<Time, Data> mData;

public:    
    void insert(Data value)
    {
        mData.insert(std::make_pair(Clock::now(), value));
    }

    void clearOlderThan(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
    {
        Time now = Clock::now();
        remove_if(mData.begin(),
                  mData.end(),
                  [ms, now](const std::pair<Time, Data> &elem) {
                      return elem.first < (now - ms);
                  });
    }
};
```

And here the template instantiation:

```
TimeSlideWindow<unsigned long, std::chrono::steady_clock> window;
window.clearOlderThan(std::chrono::milliseconds(3));
```

Can you explain where is the problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`remove_if` works by assignment, and it doesn't work on maps (or sets) because their key is `const`<sup>1</sup>. (It also doesn't actually remove the elements from the container, hence the erase-remove idiom.)

LFTS v2 has [`erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/map/erase_if) for this purpose. The linked page also shows an implementation that you can use.

Also, since `map` keeps its elements in sorted order, you may be better off doing a search (with `lower_bound`) followed by a range erase. Assuming that `Time` has more precision than `milliseconds` so that `now - ms` is convertible to `Time`:

```
auto x = mData.lower_bound(now - ms);
mData.erase(mData.begin(), x);
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Technically, it's not `const` for sets, but sets only provide `const` access to its elements.</sub>